# Regex: match variable array of item discarding optional text

Tags: python, regex

I need to split up some strings in a very large array where strings are of the form:

```
example = [
    "IV - Some text",
    "A) Some other text",
    "17-ter) an article",
    "2), 3) some ugly grouping",
    "Some text without any prefix!",
    "2), 3) some ugly grouping with (parenthesis)"
]
```

I have this code:

```
import re
s = "b), c) molto altro testo per l\'estrattore"
re.match("(?:([\d\w-]+)[\), \-])*(.*)", s).groups()
```

The above code yelds:

```
('b', ", c) molto altro testo per l'estrattore")
```

my expected result, however, is `('b', 'c', 'molto altro testo per l'estrattore')`.

Comment: This might be close to what you need: `re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=\))|[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?= - )|(?<!\S)[^-)]+$)', s)`

Comment: Thanks @Nick. You help me very much, I accomplished with `re.findall(r"'?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=\))|[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?= - )|(?<!\S)[^- ].+)'?", i)` to solve other string cases, and that's all. I would promote your comment as correct answer: can we?

Comment: I'm glad that was helpful. I would suggest that you edit your question with the other cases that you needed to adapt the regex for, and then post your regex as an answer. That will make it most useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Upon Nick's comment, I solved with this regex:

```
for i in example:
    print(re.findall(r"'?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=\))|[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?= - )|(?<!\S)[^- ].+)", i))
```

Output:

```
['IV', 'Some text']
['A', 'Some other text']
['17-ter', 'an article']
['2', '3', 'some ugly grouping']
['Some text without any prefix!']
['2', '3', 'some ugly grouping with (parenthesis)']
```